Django app; Default User ID and model field 'Trader ID' not equal
I am creating an app to allow users to enter stock trades, for record keeping. I am using Django's default User model for login and authentication. My intention is to allow the logged in user to view only their own 'Entries', which is my model for stock record entries. To this end, I have created a one to Many relationship in my Entry model named 'trader' which points to the User ID (they should be the same).
After logging in though, I don't see ANY trades on the screen even though they have been entered. I checked the Database, and the Entry.trader.id is the same number as the User.id (1 in the case of the first user created). Very strange.
What I tried: I tried removing this line from my views.py EntryView class:
entries = Entry.objects.filter(trader_id=logged_in_user).order_by("entered_date") 

and replacing it with:
entries = Entry.objects.all()

This works (proving that the records are there)but now it shows ALL of the entries.
My models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Entry(models.Model):
    ONEORB="1-Min ORB"
    FIVEORB="5-Min ORB"
    ABCD="ABCD"
    REVERSAL="Reversal"
    PROFIT="Profit"
    LOSS="Loss"
    RESULT_CHOICES = (
        (PROFIT, "Profit"),
        (LOSS, "Loss")
    )
    STRATEGY_CHOICES = (
        (ONEORB,"1-Min ORB"),
        (FIVEORB,"5-Min ORB"),
        (ABCD,"ABCD"),
        (REVERSAL,"Reversal")
    )

    entered_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    ticker=models.CharField(max_length=8, default="")
    strategy=models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=STRATEGY_CHOICES, default="ONEORB")
    result=models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=RESULT_CHOICES, default="PROFIT")
    comments=models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="", null=True, blank=True) #will save to default BASE_DIR which is 'uploads'
    trader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name="entries")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.result} {self.entered_date}"

My views.py:
from django.forms.models import BaseModelForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import EntryForm, CreateUserForm, LoginForm
from .models import Entry
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView, FormView
# Authentication models and functions
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
#this is to ensure that even after you have your login setup, a user can't just manually type in the URL
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


# Create your views here. 

class EntryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
  login_url = 'login'
  def get(self, request):
    logged_in_user = request.user.id
    entries = Entry.objects.filter(trader_id=logged_in_user).order_by("entered_date") #trader"_" id instead of .id is just django syntax
    #entries = Entry.objects.all()
    form = EntryForm()
    return render(request, "entries.html", {"form":form, "entries":entries, "user":logged_in_user})
  
  def post(self, request):
    form = EntryForm(request.POST, request.FILES) #must add request.FILES for uploads
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      messages.success(request, "Entry created!")
      return redirect("/")
    else:
      messages.error(request, "Please correct the errors below.")
      return render(request, "entries.html", {"form":form})

    
def SingleEntryView(request, pk):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Initialize the form with the existing Entry data
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=entry)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Set the user and save the updated data
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            # Redirect to a success page (e.g., 'index')
    else:
        # Initialize the form with the existing Entry data
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    context = {'form': form, 'entry': entry}
    return render(request, "single_entry.html", context)
  
class SingleEntryDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView): 
  template_name = "single_entry.html"
  model = Entry
  success_url = reverse_lazy("index")
  success_message = "Entry has been deleted."

  def delete(self, request):
    messages.success(self.request, "Successfully deleted.")
    return super().delete()

def register(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
       form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          print("User data created")
          form.instance.user = request.user
          form.save()
          return redirect("/") 
    
    else:
       form = CreateUserForm()

    context = {'registerform':form}
    return render(request, "register.html", context)   
  
# class RegisterFormView(FormView):
#    form = CreateUserForm
#    template_name = "register.html"
#    success_url = "/"

#    def form_valid(self, form):
#       form.save()
#       return super().form_valid(form)

class LoginUserView(LoginView):
   form = LoginForm
   redirect_authenticated_user = True
   template_name = "login.html"
   next_page = "/"
   authentication_form = LoginForm
   context = {'form':form}

   def form_invalid(self, form):
      messages.error(self.request, 'Invalid usename or password')
      return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))


My entries.html (index page):
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

{% block title %}
    Trading Journal
{% endblock title %}Trading Journal

{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <h1>Request.user.id:{{request.user.id}}</h1>
{% endblock content %}

{% block table %}

<table class="blueTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Ticker</th>
    <th>Strategy</th>
    <th>Result</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <div class="links"><a href="#">&laquo;</a> <a class="active" href="#">1</a> <a href="#">2</a> <a href="#">3</a> <a href="#">4</a> <a href="#">&raquo;</a></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        {% for entry in entries %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'single-entry' entry.id %}">{{entry.entered_date}}</a></td><td>{{entry.ticker}}</td><td>{{entry.strategy}}</td><td>{{entry.result}}</td><td>{{entry.comments}}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    
    </tbody>
    </tr>
    </table>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}"><button>Logout</button></a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock table %}


My urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView 

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.EntryView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path("entries/<int:pk>/delete", views.SingleEntryDeleteView.as_view(), name="single-entry-delete"),
    path("entries/<int:pk>/", views.SingleEntryView, name="single-entry"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("login/", views.LoginUserView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path("logout/", views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page="login"), name="logout"),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls)
]


My forms.py:
from django import forms
from .models import Entry

# Authentication modules start here
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput

# Form to create a journal entry
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Entry
        exclude = ["trader"]

# Create / register a user
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User #default django User model
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


# Authenticate a user
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())




Your EntryForm excludes the trader field and I don't see you setting it to the logged in user anywhere. How did you create these entries?

@AbdulAzizBarkat That's because its not selected or entered by the user. It's assigned automatically; it should correspond to the default User.id created by Django. See this line in models.py: trader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name="entries")

You don't have any default on the foreign key...

@AbdulAzizBarkat you're right I just reviewed my code and I didn't assign any value. I have added it to my view before the form.save(): form.instance.trader = request.user

I assumed that my model would assign a value to 'trader' when defining the 'Entry' model, but I now see I needed to explicitly assign it a value in my view. I have added this line in my views.py, before the form.save() is called:
if form.is_valid():
      form.instance.trader = request.user 
      form.save()

